# My website is listening for the port 8080 but not for port 80 ( which is default in url)

Tags: amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I have an ec2 instance with ubuntu . I have installed tomcat7 in it.I have domain name from godaddy.Can any one please guide me how should i configure tomcat in ubuntu to listen for port 80. Although i have allready tried with authbind and ip tables but those are not helping . Please help me to set up my fast website.
I have added port 80 in my security groups for the inbound and outbound rules also.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that default installation of Tomcat 7 for Linux Debian allows to bind only ports higher than 1023. You need to allow binding to privileged ports.

Open file /etc/defaults/tomcat7 and change option from:

```
#AUTHBIND=no
```

to:

```
AUTHBIND=yes
```

Restart Tomcat and it will listen on port 80.

Comment: i did.but still my domain is not working. Its working with mydomain.com:8080 only not with mydomain.com.

Comment: i changed the port from 8080 to 80 in server.xml and made the AUTHBIND=yes.
 -->
    <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               redirectPort="8443" />

but now i can not open a web page using either mydomain.com or mydomain.com:8080. please help.